# why the following down casting is not working in Java:

Tags: java

```
    ArrayList<classA> aList = /*I then fill this array*/
    ArrayList<classB> bList = /* I then fill this array too*/

    /*Now put them both in the following ArrayList of Objects*/
    ArrayList<Object> myObjs =  new ArrayList<Object>();
    myObjs.add(aList);
    myObjs.add(bList);

    /*The following two lines however fails at run time*/
    ArrayList<classA> x = (ArrayList<classA>) myObjs.get(0);
    ArrayList<classB> x = (ArrayList<classB>) myObjs.get(1);
```

I just read from another thread that "Downcasting is allowed when there is a possibility that it succeeds at run time "

can any one please tell me the problem of the above code ?
thank you very much!

Comment: It's because Java collections are not covariant. A `List<Foo>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, despite the fact that `Foo` is a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: If you have an answer to the question, you should probably post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java Tutorials on Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html):

*Consider the following method:*

```
public void boxTest(Box<Number> n) { /* ... */ }
```

*What type of argument does it accept? By looking at its signature, you can see that it accepts a single argument whose type is `Box<Number>`. But what does that mean? Are you allowed to pass in `Box<Integer>` or `Box<Double>`, as you might expect? The answer is "no", becaue `Box<Integer>` and `Box<Double>` are not subtypes of `Box<Number>`.*

In other words: Even though `classA` is a subclass of `Object`, `ArrayList<classA>` is **not** a subtype of `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: This is what "Java collections are not covariant" means.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that casting an `Object` to `classA` is not the same as casting `ArrayList<Object>`to `ArrayList<classA>`. Also, you should use the class name as a template parameter, rather than the object name.

Comment: "Also, you should use the class name as a template parameter, rather than the object name":
yes, that is right I just made mistake while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that this was interesting question. I've been fiddling with an example code and this works!! You can try this code in this amazing Online IDE Tool - http://ideone.com/ which compiles and shows your code's output online for free.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyClass{

public static void main(String []args){

ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(10);
a.add(100);

ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
b.add("10");
b.add("100");

ArrayList<ArrayList> o = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
o.add(a);
o.add(b);

a = o.get(0);
b= o.get(1);

System.out.println("int"+a.get(0));
System.out.println("string"+b.get(0));

System.out.println("Online IDE Works");
}

}
```

The problem is you're having an ArrayList of ArrayLists itself. Downcasting doesn't work with Objects to ArrayLists. However as in the above example code, if you give the param as an ArrayList itself without providing generic type for the inner ArrayList, then you get a perfect output!

Comment: In my case (if possible) casting is a must, because I will call a method of classA using its object, which otherwise is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I just tried that with a = (ArrayList<Integer>)o.get(0); and b= (ArrayList<String>)o.get(1). It does work!

Comment: Yes, it will work for what you said: (to down cast ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<Integer>) and that is why some said before that "Downcasting is allowed when there is a possibility that it succeeds at run time "
but in my case the cast is from  ArrayList<Object> to ArrayList<myCLass>, that is where the problem occurs: "Java collections are not covariant" which in turn happens by the fact that collections are mutable.